# Setting eclipse plugin start level using p2.inf file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, p2

I've been following the instructions [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Setting_Start_Levels) and [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata) to try and control the bundle start level using a p2.inf file.

I have written the p2.inf file and confirmed that the repository content.xml file now appears to have the relevant instructions in:

```
      <instruction key='configure'>
        org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.setStartLevel(startLevel:3); org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.markStarted(started:true);
      </instruction>
```

However when I install the result and use the bundlelevel command on the osgi console, it doesn't seem to have taken effect.

I have no apparent error messages in my normal workspace/.metadata/.log file.

Is setting the start level from p2.inf supposed to work?

How would I diagnose why it isn't?

(I'm using Eclipse Neon as my target runtime if it makes a difference)

Thanks.

Comment: p2.inf does not work with XML tags, but ses key-value pairs